# Session scoped beans are viewed in other users session

Tags: spring, security, jsf

I am using spring 3.1 , spring security 3.1 , primefaces with jsf 2.0 .

I have created a login page with just simple `username` and `password`, this page is linked to a session scoped bean which has a username and password.

When say for example `user x` access the website and still not logged out, when someone else in another place view the login page, the username value which `user x` has written appears automatically in the username field.

How can I overcome that problem?

Comment: You question is extremely confusing. You should try and clarify what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Are beans managed by JSF or Spring? Show how they are managed.

Comment: Do you have any static fields in your managed bean?